# Find value or check if value exists in object

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have a object like:

```
["1", "2", "1", "2"]
```

No i want to check if "1" exists in object. I don't need to know how often it exists.

`$.inArray(1, myObject)` -> Returns always -1

So what is wrong or what i have to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're checking for an integer, when the array contains only strings. Also be advised that jQuery's `inArray()` function does not act like its PHP counterpart. Rather than returning `true` or `false`, it returns the actual zero-based index of the value if found (as an integer), or `-1` if it isn't in the array.

Try this:

```
if($.inArray('1', myObject) >= 0) 
{
    // Do your stuff.
}
```

Here's a [jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/5WXTk/)

Comment: Works great. I think my Problem was to search for integer. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Or you can use plain JS:

```
var x = ["1", "2", "1", "2"];

if (x.indexOf("1") !== -1) {
    console.log("found");
} else {
    console.log("not found");
}
```

Comment: Thank you too but i use the jQuery-Funkction.